# Cant seem to import libgdx generated folders

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I've been following this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rVS1zHThZ0

and at about 3:30 he says to import the folders that are generated when you open and run the libgdx setup that he asked us to download. Now in the video his works fine, but when I try to import the generated folders I get this message "No projects are found to import". I've done some research but cant seem to find an answer as to why these folders don't even appear in eclipse for me to import them. If anyone has any ideas as to why kindly let me know.

thank you,

jen

Comment: These instructions are correct, so you must be deviating from them somewhere. Try selecting one directory up from the project when importing in Eclipse.

Comment: Whatever folder you are clicking in the "Browse for Folder" window, instead click the folder that contains it before pressing OK.

Comment: These are obsolete directions however. Libgdx has moved on to the Gradle-based setup of future versions of the Android SDK. I highly recommend using the Gradle-based setup with Android Studio. This is the future of Android and Libgdx development, so if you're just getting started, you should learn the new way rather than have to learn the old way right before it becomes obsolete. Gradle has already saved me a huge amount of time. I used to have to juggle multiple projects for the free and paid versions of my app, but now I can generate the multiple APKs with just a couple clicks.

Comment: ok what is Gradle based and could you send me a link to the location and perhaps how it works, and or how to do it?

Comment: ok i got it to import. What I did wrong was file- import- Android- existing Android project. what I did was import gradle then browse. I did encounter an error tho .

Comment: All the instructions are on the official site here: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.htmlhttp://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html  Follow the instructions for Intellij IDEA if using Android Studio (it's the same thing).